# Why capturing by reference in lambda doesn't change the type of the variables?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I thought that capturing by reference changes the types of the variables. Lets consider the following example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int& x_ref = x;
    const int x_const = x;
    const int& x_const_ref = x_const;

    auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x), int>::value, "!");
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x_ref), int&>::value, "!");
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x_const), const int>::value, "!");
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(x_const_ref), const int&>::value, "!");
    };

    lambda();
}
```

None of the checks failed, so the type of original variables are preserved. So, how capturing by reference really works? I thought if user captures by reference, new variables with the same name are introduced to the local scope to have reference type of the original variables. But it seems like it is not the case.

**Question:** what is the motivation for this? Or is it me misunderstanding something?

Comment: `decltype` gives you the _declared_ type; being inside a lambda doesn't affect the declaration, so it doesn't affect `decltype`.

Comment: @ildjarn, thanks for suggestion. Gonna check out `decltype` in more detail.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, done. I hope that I didn't strip off anything needed.

Comment: @ildjarn, I've read through [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) page a few times, but still I don't really get the point.

Comment: @Incomputable check my answer. Also, you can try to capture a single variable first, to check if I am correct about 16 bytes (in answer I mentioned it)

Comment: @andrgolubev, should I try to do `sizeof()`?

Comment: @Incomputable : I don't really know how to clarfify... It's straightforward: the type in the declaration of `x` (`int x = 0;`) is `int`, so `decltype(x)` is `int`.

Comment: @ildjarn, for some reason I read it like "it never gives you declared type". May be I'm just too tired. So, the answer is that lambdas doesn't affect declaration?

Comment: @Incomputable no, just the same thing. but only for single variable at once. The point is, that there's a chance that `lambda` will be treated as **function pointer** - so, you wouldn't get any implicit conversions to object members (this would likely help to preserve the _references_)

Comment: @Incomputable : Simple-captures aren't declarations, and as we know, it's the declaration that matters to `decltype`.

Comment: @andrgolubev, nothing changed.

Comment: For further experiments (with things captured by copy), I recommend using `decltype((n))` instead of `decltype(n)`, because the latter always refers to the original declaration, while the former behaves as-if it referred to the member of the closure type (even if the name is not actually captured!). Then it will give you the type of the expression. AFAIK, with `decltype` you cannot get the type of the member declaration of the closure type. Either you get the type of the original declaration, or the expression type of the closure member reference (makes a diff for `mutable`/default lambdas).

Comment: Also relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1913 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2011

Comment: BTW you don't need `#include <cassert>` to use `static_assert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought if user captures by reference, new variables with the same name are introduced to the local scope to have reference type of the original variables.

The standard says (emphasis mine):

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly captured but not captured by copy. **It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference**. If declared, such non-static data members shall be of literal type.

Therefore your expectations were wrong. Capturing by reference doesn't mean *create a local reference to an object in the outer scope*.

---

As a side note, consider the following:

```
int x;
auto l = [&x](){ return [&x](){} }();
```

If your expectations were right, `x` would have been a *reference to a reference* within the lambda `l`, that is something that doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: The answer is already great. Could you please also add, if applicable, the motivation for this?

Comment: @Incomputable Added more details. Let me know if you want more.

Comment: `int i = 0; auto & j = i; auto & k = j;` by analogy there is shouldn't be a reference to reference.

Comment: @Orient It is slightly different. In your case you are initializing a reference with _something_. What the OP said instead is that the local variable was a reference to a variable in the outer scope, therefore a reference to a reference - not a reference initialized with. I don't know how to explain it better, but I hope you got it.

Comment: @skypjack I'm not sure that's what OP said.

Comment: @Oktalist He said - _if user captures by reference, new variables with the same name are introduced to the local scope to have reference type of the original variables_. In this case, I read it as if a _reference type of the original variable_ for (as an example) a `int &` would have been a reference to a reference. Anyway, OP is the only one that can say what he meant.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with something simple:

```
int x = 0;
auto lambda = [=]{ return x; };
```

What does `return x` actually do there? The "obvious" answer is that it returns the value of `lambda`'s member variable named `x`. But that isn't actually the case. The lambda doesn't have a member named `x` - the lambda's data members itself are unnamed. What happens it that:

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a lambda-expression that is an odr-use (3.2) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.

When you *use* `x`, you're actually referring to the appropriate member variable. So the above expression could be interpreted as:

```
struct __unnamed {
    int _1;

    __unnamed(int i) : _1(i) { }
    void operator=(__unnamed const&) = delete;
    int operator() const { return _1; }
};

__unnamed lambda(x);
```

The point of why I'm saying this is... there's only one `x` here. The `int x` variable. So when you do `decltype(x)`, that gives you the **decl**ared **type** of `x`. Which is, of course, `int`. That doesn't change if you capture by reference, because the capture of your lambda doesn't change the types of the variables your capturing.

---

Now, if you *did* want to access those unnamed members of the lambda, you could do that. But instead of `decltype(x)` you want `decltype((x))`:

> Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where `x` is a possibly parenthesized *id-expression* that names an entity of automatic storage duration is treated as if `x` were transformed into an access to a corresponding data member of the closure type that would have been declared if `x` were an odr-use of the denoted entity.

That is, while in your example, `decltype(x)` is `int` and `decltype(x_const)` is `int const`... `decltype((x))` is `int&` and `decltype((x_const))` is `int const&`. This is probably more what you were actually looking for. Because now we're actually referring to the lambda's members,  or at least as if we were. But note here that the usual `decltype((id))` rules still apply, so you will always get reference types for lvalues.

Comment: Thanks for additional information, but I use it inside of `scope_exit`, which just executes the lambda inside of the destructor of more or less "hidden" class. So the only thing that matters in that situation is the way the variables are accessed, e.g. if any operations on `x` will be the same as performing it on `x` outside of the lambda. Your answer answers the question though.

Comment: @skypjack I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Barry I mean, you said - _Because now we're actually referring to the lambda's members, and the lambda's members must, of course, be references - since that's what you specified_. That's true, but it seems to me pointless for he's asking about capture by reference and unnamed members are not mandatory in that case. What did I miss in your reasoning?

Comment: @skypjack OP is asking why `decltype(x)` isn't a reference even tho were capturing by reference. The answer is because we're not asking for the lambdas member. But `decltype((x))` is because it does.

Comment: The key point is "that is an odr-use". `decltype(x)` isn't an odr-use, so the `x` always refers to the entity in the surrounding scope rather than the capture.

Comment: @Barry Then it's me that misunderstood the OP's question - _So, how capturing by reference really works?_. I thought he was asking about how capturing by reference works, not about `decltype`. :-)

Comment: "Because now we're actually referring to the lambda's members, and the lambda's members must, of course, be references - since that's what you specified." - I dont't think that is correct at all. According to the spec, no closure members are created for references, instead it is left unspecified. Because of that, the spec does not at all specify the type of any additional members declared for reference captures on behalf of an implementation. According to the spec, any use of reference captured variables refer to the original variables, no transformation ever happens.

Comment: In addition you said "and the lambda's members must, of course, be references - since that's what you specified.", which is confusing because he will get reference types `const int&` and `const int&` *even if he captured by copy*. Because the expressions will be *lvalues* and the lambda is not `mutable`.

Comment: Also relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1913 and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2011

Comment: @Johannes I changed that wording. It's difficult to come up with a way to explain this in just a paragraph, but I didn't want to write 3...